# Out of process Session state Stopped working?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, state-management

I have a shopping cart, and I want the products in the cart to remain even when the application is closed and restarted.  I set up out of process session state, and it actually did work(for a while).

I have made no changes to my application or sqlserver, however now when I test my shopping cart(about an hour later), the data no longer persist when I close the browser or restart the application.

My ASP.Net State service is still running, and I have my classes set as [serializable], nothing has changed.

Below is how I configure my session state in web.config

```
  <sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=.\***;Initial Catalog=aspnet;Integrated Security=True;Database=ASPState;User ID=***;Password=***" timeout="180" useHostingIdentity="true" />
```

Has anyone had this issue(or know of a solution) where out of process session state works for the first few test(the data correctly persist), but randomly stops working later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name implies, session state is only good for the current browser session.
You'll need to save the shopping cart to a more permanent structure if you need to keep it longer than the browser session.  A new session id, which is the key used to retrieve session state data, is assigned with each visit.

The implication is you will also either need a persistent cookie, or provide the user with an identity to retrieve the cart later.